# How to Reset EMV Prepaid Debit Card Offline Funds

Tags: c, emv

I have gone through the development path for qVSCD(Quick Visa Smart Debit/Credit), as specified in "Visa Contactless Payment Specification v2.0.2" and have successfully implemented all the steps in C language. However they do not specify how to implement the Reset of Offline Counters and have only mentioned it briefly in section 8.3. Anyone with any technical knowhow on this?

I want to develop an EMV application for prepaid debit cards where can use and add to their offline balance (through top-up).
I am developing on C language for Bitel terminal.
Thanks.

Comment: The VCPS 2.0.2 spec is clearly pointing you to the VIS 1.4 spec on this topic. Did you take a look there?

Comment: Thanks. I've gone through VIS 1.4 Card Spec and yes they talk of PUT DATA and UPDATE RECORD commands, though not in sufficient detail. I presume these are the ones I will use to achieve my goal??

Comment: Yes, particularly PUT DATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different possible ways to reset the counters as mentioned in VCPS 2.0.2 section 8.3. 
The spec is clearly pointing you to the VIS 1.4 spec on this topic. You will find further details there.